# openpyxlを使った空白の判定

Tags: python, python3, excel, openpyxl

#### やりたいこと

Excelからデータを読み込み空白のセル(管理番号)を判定させて
空白の場合、A列の管理番号を次の行に代入して貼り付ける。

**Excelのデータ:**

```
管理番号         申込電話番号    電話番号情報
96103212345       0344123902      無
                  0344123903      無
                  0344123904      無
                  0344123905      無
96103212346       0344123906      無
                  0344123907      無
                  0344123908      無
96103212347       0344123909      無
96103212348       0344123910      無
```

**現在の結果空白を削除されます。:**

```
['96103212345', '0354379020', '無']
['96103212346', '0344123906', '無']
['96103212347', '0344123909', '無']
['96103212348', '0344123910', '無']
```

コード

```
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
print(v_ws)

# 空白文字を判定⇒参考https://gammasoft.jp/support/openpyxl-iter-rows/
for row in v_ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    if row[0].value is None:
        continue
    values = []
    for col in row:
        values.append(col.value)
    print(values)
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「openpyxlを使った空白の判定」と「seleniumを使った操作」はそれぞれ分けて質問すべきだと思います。

Comment: @sakaolo さん、ちなみに「seleniumを使った操作」については、交通費検索の結果として表示される操作対象のHtml/CSSがどのようなものであるかの情報が無いと、助言や回答が難しいでしょう。ただしログインが必要だと誰でも試すという訳にはいかないし、結果ページをそのままコピペして提示では著作権に抵触するでしょうから、情報提示も難しいところですね。

Comment: 上記の指摘ありがとうございます。新規で質問します

Answer (score 2, accepted):

空白判定の参考記事の「先頭カラムが空欄でない行だけ読み取る」処理を何も変更せずにコピーしているようですが、これだと空欄のある行をスキップして表示するだけで、しかもexcelデータには何も反映されないままですね。
参考記事および実現したい内容の両方が上手く整理されていないために理解し切れていないのでしょう。

おそらく以下の内容のシートが：

```
申込書管理番号      申込電話番号    電話番号情報
96103212345       0344123902      無
                  0344123903      無
                  0344123904      無
                  0344123905      無
96103212346       0344123906      無
                  0344123907      無
                  0344123908      無
96103212347       0344123909      無
96103212348       0344123910      無
```

こちらのように空欄に直前の値が補完されれば良いのでは？

```
申込書管理番号      申込電話番号    電話番号情報
96103212345       0344123902      無
96103212345       0344123903      無
96103212345       0344123904      無
96103212345       0344123905      無
96103212346       0344123906      無
96103212346       0344123907      無
96103212346       0344123908      無
96103212347       0344123909      無
96103212348       0344123910      無
```

なので申込書管理番号のためにentrynumberといった変数を用意し、空欄だったらそれを代入する・空欄でなかったらそれでentrynumberを入れ替える、という処理にすれば良いでしょう。
参考記事からコピーしたここの部分を：

```
for row in v_ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    if row[0].value is None:
        continue
    values = []
    for col in row:
        values.append(col.value)
    print(values)
```

こちらのようにしてみてください。
ifの条件を増やしたのは、参考記事の空白文字が入っていた場合を反映したものです。

```
entrynumber = ''
for i in range(2,v_ws.max_row+1):
    if v_ws['a'+str(i)].value is None or not str(v_ws['a'+str(i)].value).strip():
        v_ws['a'+str(i)].value = entrynumber
    else:
        entrynumber = v_ws['a'+str(i)].value
```

---

あるいは、その申込書管理番号部分のexcelのデータを書き変えたくないなら、交通費検索ループの処理を変えるのが良いでしょう。
こちらの部分を：

```
for i in range(2,v_ws.max_row+1):

    # 申込書管理番号
    a = v_ws['a'+str(i)].value

    # 申込電話番号
    b = v_ws['b'+str(i)].value
```

このように変えてみてはどうでしょう。

```
entrynumber = ''
for i in range(2,v_ws.max_row+1):

    # 申込書管理番号
    a = v_ws['a'+str(i)].value

    if a is None or not str(a).strip():
        a = entrynumber
    else:
        entrynumber = a

    # 申込電話番号
    b = v_ws['b'+str(i)].value
```

Comment: いつも丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
そのままExcelのデータを変えずに交通費検索ループの処理のように行いたいですが、`if line02NttPhoneNumber1 == b:`
コードで記載しているようにエクセルで申込書管理番号（A列）が空白で申込電話番号（b列）2個以上がある場合、どのようにb列0344123903の次の行をWEB上で判定すればよろしいでしょうか。もしわかれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: Excel上のデータの話ではなくWebで処理した結果取得したデータに関してというなら、それは`openpyxl`では無いので別の質問を立てた方が良いでしょう。 特に「OKのボタンをクリック」とか「続き要素をスクロールして番号を判定」とかはExcelの話ではなくWebブラウザ操作の話ですよね。両者を混ぜて考えているから「処理が複雑な為」と言う風に混乱するのでは？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問内容を修正いたしました。

Comment: 元の質問は、それはそれで意味があるでしょうから、内容を書き変えるのではなく新規に別の質問を起こした方が良いと思われます。

Comment: かしこまりました。新規で質問致します。